Using expkv-def with newtcblisting to pass the minted language parameter as optional argument
I created a customized tcolorbox which contains a minted environment. I want to use it flexibly so that optional parameters being passed via the expkv-def package control some parts of the box's appearance.
If I call the code with arguments for title and font everything works as expected. But using another argument for lang (in order to control the minted language option) does not work and throws an error message.
For example:
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{dunkelgrau}{gray}{0.7}
\definecolor{hellgrau}{cmyk}{0,0,0,.08}
\definecolor{weiss}{cmyk}{0,0,0,0}

\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage[most,minted]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\usepackage{expkv-def}

\usepackage{minted}
\tcbuselibrary{listings,minted}

\ekvdefinekeys{codebox}
{
   store title = \mycodeboxTitle
  ,store font = \mycodeboxFont
  ,store lang = \mycodeboxLang
  ,initial lang = cpp
}

\newtcblisting{codebox}[2][]{%
    breakable,
    colback=hellgrau,
    coltitle=weiss,
    colbacktitle=dunkelgrau,
    colframe=dunkelgrau,
    boxrule=0.9pt,
    boxsep=5pt,
    arc=1pt,
    fonttitle=\sffamily,
    toptitle=0mm,
    bottomtitle=0mm,
    left=3pt,
    right=3pt,
    listing only,
    code={\ekvset{codebox}{#1}},
    title={
      \ifstrequal{#2}{file}{\faFile*[regular]\hspace{5mm}}{%
        \ifstrequal{#2}{console}{\faTerminal\hspace{5mm}}{%
          \ifstrequal{#2}{info}{\faInfo\hspace{5mm}}{%
            \ifstrequal{#2}{book}{\faBookOpen\hspace{5mm}}{}%
          }
        }
      }\mycodeboxTitle
    },
    minted options app={
        fontsize=\mycodeboxFont
    },
    minted language=\mycodeboxLang,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{codebox}[title=include/adjustSpeed.hpp, font=\small, lang=cpp]{file}
#include <string>

std::string getHello() {
    return "Hello World";
}
\end{codebox}

\end{document}

Then I receive the following error message:
Error: no lexer for alias '\\mycodeboxLang ' found


! Package minted Error: Missing Pygments output; \inputminted was
probably given a file that does not exist--otherwise, you may need 
the outputdir package option, or may be using an incompatible build tool,
or may be using frozencache with a missing file.

See the minted package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.64 \end{codebox}
                
? 

Does anyone know how this could be fixed?

For people not using the latest version of minted that still want to achieve something like this (specifying the language as a macro), you need to expand that macro before minted gets its argument.
Since tcolorbox uses pgfkeys under the hood you can use the .expand once handler to achieve that like the following (this MWE explicitly loads minted2 which is the old version of minted to demonstrate that this indeed works):
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{dunkelgrau}{gray}{0.7}
\definecolor{hellgrau}{cmyk}{0,0,0,.08}
\definecolor{weiss}{cmyk}{0,0,0,0}

\usepackage{minted2}

\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage[most,minted]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\usepackage{expkv-def}

\usepackage{minted}
\tcbuselibrary{listings,minted}

\ekvdefinekeys{codebox}
{
   store title = \mycodeboxTitle
  ,store font = \mycodeboxFont
  ,store lang = \mycodeboxLang
  ,initial lang = cpp
}

\newtcblisting{codebox}[2][]{%
    breakable,
    colback=hellgrau,
    coltitle=weiss,
    colbacktitle=dunkelgrau,
    colframe=dunkelgrau,
    boxrule=0.9pt,
    boxsep=5pt,
    arc=1pt,
    fonttitle=\sffamily,
    toptitle=0mm,
    bottomtitle=0mm,
    left=3pt,
    right=3pt,
    listing only,
    code={\ekvset{codebox}{#1}},
    title={
      \ifstrequal{#2}{file}{\faFile*[regular]\hspace{5mm}}{%
        \ifstrequal{#2}{console}{\faTerminal\hspace{5mm}}{%
          \ifstrequal{#2}{info}{\faInfo\hspace{5mm}}{%
            \ifstrequal{#2}{book}{\faBookOpen\hspace{5mm}}{}%
          }
        }
      }\mycodeboxTitle
    },
    minted options app={
        fontsize=\mycodeboxFont
    },
    minted language/.expand once=\mycodeboxLang,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{codebox}[title=include/adjustSpeed.hpp, font=\small, lang=cpp]{file}
#include <string>

std::string getHello() {
    return "Hello World";
}
\end{codebox}

\end{document}


It seems like an update of the minted package (starting with version 3.0) automatically resolves this issue. This was just released one month ago so that an update of my TeXLive installation did the trick.
Thanks a lot to the authors of this fantastic package.

